# How do I programmatically "restart" an Android app in.Net maui?

Tags: java, android, maui

How do I programmatically "restart" an Android app in.Net maui?

I have been trying to restart the application when the system reboot in .net maui app

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.companyname.mauiapp3.BootBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

BootBroadcastReceiver.cs

```
using global::Android.App;
using global::Android.Content; 

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true,Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
  public class BootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
   public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
      i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
      context.StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    BootBroadcastReceiver receiver;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        receiver = new BootBroadcastReceiver();
    }
}
```

I already tried all answers related to this in stackoverflow it is not working.

Environment: visual studio 2022 .NET MAUI version: MAUI 7.0

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to launch your activity at startup-  you can't.  A broadcast receiver of a bakgrounded app cannot launch a foreground activity on modern android.

If this is because you're writing a kiosk app, consider writing a launcher app to replace the home screen.  If this is any other app, the best you can do is put up a notification.